# Why I need to use object desctructuring to properly change value of controlled input with React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I use object destructuring everything works fine but if write it without it after two keystrokes I get few errors.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";



function App() {
  const [people, setPerson] = useState([{ name: "", lastName: "" }]);

  const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setPerson(prevState => [{ ...prevState[index], [event.target.name]: event.target.value }]);
  };

  useEffect(() => console.log(people));

  return (
    <div>
      {people.map((person, index) => (
        <form key={index}>
          <input
            placeholder="name"
            value={person.name}
            name="name"
            onChange={event => handleChange(event, index)}
          />
          <input
            placeholder="lastName"
            value={person.lastName}
            name="lastName"
            onChange={event => handleChange(event, index)}
          />
        </form>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Here is the link to codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-controled-input-oe11p)

Please see on errors. Is it because of hooks?

Comment: Your codesandbox IS using destructuring and is working. I commented out your variable destructure and added a variable assign for each (name, value) and it still works just fine. Can you show us an example of it NOT working?

Comment: name and value is destructured but it's not used this way. Later on it is written explicitly [event.target.name]: event.target.value and it's not working. The same is here and the same is in codesandbox. I don't know why it works in your case. After second keystroke there should be error in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function in question is this:

```
const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setPerson(prevState => [{ ...prevState[index], [event.target.name]: event.target.value }]);
  };
```

The reason this fails when typing is that it's attempting to reference an event that has already been released. To prevent the error, you can persist the event until the completion of the function. This also works when passing an event between functions.

```
const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    event.persist()
    const { name, value } = event.target;

    setPerson(prevState => [{ ...prevState[index], [event.target.name]: event.target.value }]);
  };
```

The reason it works when destructing is because creation a constant creates a clone of the information at that time that will persist within its scope.